# Using isEnabled() for a test control

Tags: webdriver

I am using PageObject model in developing test scripts. I am trying to put into test code control of a current situation. In my case it is an element enabled or not. The source code below.

```java
    @FindBy(linkText="Overview")
    private WebElement overviewTab; 

    public boolean checkOverviewTabVisable() {
        return overviewTab.isEnabled();
    }

    if(customerSitePage.checkOverviewTabVisable()) {
        customerSitePage.getOverviewTab();
    } else {
        sitesTabsList.getBuyerSite();
        customerSitePage.getOverviewTab();
    }
```

Script hangs in the line of checkOverviewTabVisable() method call and no any error. Something weird in isEnabled() behavior. Has anyone used this method for test control?

Comment: Yes, i tried isDisplayed(). The result was same, script hangs.

Comment: Have you tried using a different way of identifying the screen element e.g. css or xpath? Does that make any difference?